# icon "unchecked box" not changed to "checked" when clicked in list report

Tags: abap

I can display checkbox in list report and single click is also working as well.

I am also able to read current row of list using AT LINE-SELECTION event.

Can anyone help?

The problem is checkbox icon is not updated when checkbox is clicked.I tried to find solution, and tried to fix it my self but could not do it.

Sample code is below.

```
TYPE-POOLS:icon.

CONSTANTS:
          c_unchecked TYPE icon_d VALUE icon_wd_iframe,
          c_checked TYPE icon_d VALUE icon_checkbox.


TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_data,
          carrid TYPE  s_carr_id,
          carrname TYPE  s_carrname,
          currcode TYPE  s_currcode,
          url TYPE  s_carrurl ,
          checkbox TYPE icon_d,
       END OF ty_data.
DATA t_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_data.

START-OF-SELECTION.

SELECT CARRID,CARRNAME,CURRCODE,URL  FROM SCARR INTO TABLE @t_data.

LOOP AT t_data ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_data>).
     <fs_data>-checkbox = c_unchecked .
     WRITE:/10 <fs_data>-checkbox AS ICON HOTSPOT,
            20 <fs_data>-carrid,
            35 <fs_data>-carrname,
            60 <fs_data>-currcode,
            70 <fs_data>-url.
   ENDLOOP.

 AT LINE-SELECTION.

   READ TABLE t_data ASSIGNING <fs_data>
      INDEX sy-curow.
   IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
     IF <fs_data>-checkbox EQ c_unchecked.
       <fs_data>-checkbox = c_checked.
       REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF  c_unchecked IN sy-lisel WITH c_checked.
     ELSEIF <fs_data>-checkbox EQ c_checked.
       REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF  c_checked IN sy-lisel WITH c_unchecked.
     ENDIF.
     MODIFY LINE sy-curow.
   ENDIF.
```

Output:

[image: Listoutput with checkbox]

Answer (score 1):

Changing `AS ICON HOTSPOT` to `AS CHECKBOX` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is more a complement of @Jagger correct answer, but stackoverflow don't permit adding a big comment.

Using `AS CHECKBOX` is the best answer, because there's no reason of using an icon if you just need a checkbox.

Here is a complete code which shows how `AS CHECKBOX` works, including how to find out which lines have been selected (a secondary ABAP list is displayed with selected lines). It's important to use **global variables** (not field symbols) with an ABAP list because it's an obsolete technology and fields can be accessed only via global variables.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_data,
         carrid   TYPE  s_carr_id,
         carrname TYPE  s_carrname,
         currcode TYPE  s_currcode,
         url      TYPE  s_carrurl,
         checkbox TYPE  abap_bool,
       END OF ty_data.
DATA t_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_data.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  SELECT carrid,carrname,currcode,url  FROM scarr INTO TABLE @t_data.

  SKIP 1.
  WRITE / '@15\Qtooltip@Execute' HOTSPOT.
  SKIP 1.

  LOOP AT t_data INTO DATA(fs_data).
    fs_data-checkbox = abap_false.
    WRITE:/10 fs_data-checkbox AS CHECKBOX,
           20 fs_data-carrid,
           35 fs_data-carrname,
           60 fs_data-currcode,
           70 fs_data-url.
  ENDLOOP.

AT LINE-SELECTION.
  IF sy-lisel = '@15\Qtooltip@Execute'.
    write / 'You have selected these lines:'.
    DATA lines TYPE i.
    DESCRIBE LIST NUMBER OF LINES lines.
    DO lines TIMES.
      READ LINE sy-index FIELD VALUE fs_data-checkbox.
      IF fs_data-checkbox = 'X'.
        WRITE / sy-lisel.
      ENDIF.
    ENDDO.
  ENDIF.
```

Result :

[image: ABAP list with checkbox]

Comment: Sandra Rossi. My original requirement is different where i have to show if one vendor is selected then other vendors, cross will be displayed. For Check box , your answer might  be right but my requirement was for the icon.

Comment: @Nasir I know, my answer does not correspond to your question which is about "icons", but there's an ambiguity in your question which makes think that an icon is required for checkboxes. You may still use a real checkbox, by simply adding `HOTSPOT ON INPUT OFF` after `AS CHECKBOX` (well, it's grayed out, but still the mouse over shows it may be clicked). Anyway, I understand that your question is valid for any kind of icon, not only checkbox-like icons, so the "icon solution" will help people who have this same question (PS: I have added "icon" to the question title so that it's searchable).